# Call a function of a .js library from an Office script

Tags: office-scripts

I'm trying Office Scripts.

I have a big .js file as a library, assume there is a function `calc(x)`. I would like to be able to call this function from an Office script.

Does anyone know if it is possible? Does anyone know how to upload the .js library to Office Scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this link they're not currently supported. (See the External Library Support section): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/code-editor-environment

Answer (score 3):

If it is just a **single** .js file - as a temporary workaround, you can probably copy the whole thing and paste inside the Office Scripts code editor (you can put it before or after the `main` function). Then you can invoke `calc(x)` from inside `main()`.

It's not ideal but might work.